How can I make UserOperations more human-readable in an EOA to avoid confusion with phishing transactions?
UserOperations are becoming an increasingly popular pattern for bundling and invoking account-abstracted transactions on EVM chains. However, when these operations appear in MetaMask, they often resemble phishing transactions that could potentially drain a user's wallet, causing concern and confusion.
Is there a method or best practice for making UserOperations more transparent and human-readable in an Externally Owned Account (EOA) to reduce the likelihood of users mistaking them for phishing attempts?

Does there exist a way to make a userOp more humanly readable in an EOA?

I'm not sure what are UserOperations, but I guess it refers to just signing messages.
If you are signing a garbled message, there's no way to present it in a nice way anyway. For example, signing a timestamp.
That's why EIP-712 exists. Many wallets probably support it. With that, the signed message should be clearer for the user.
I wonder if you could just dump those UserOperations in EIP-712 messages.

UserOperations are transactions invoked on ERC4337 AA wallets :)

Right, so not something that could be altered.
